# First packet to be sent when starting to browse

Tags: browser, network-programming, network-protocols, packet, arp

Imagine a user sitting at an Ethernet-connected PC. He has a browser open. He types "www.google.com" in the address bar and hits enter.

Now tell me what the first packet to appear on the Ethernet is.

I found this question here: [Interview Questions on Socket Programming and Multi-Threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177197/interview-questions-on-socket-programming-and-multi-threading)

As I'm not a networking expert, I'd like to hear the answer (I'd assume it is "It depends" ;) ).

With a tool like Wireshark, I can obviously check my own computers behaviour. I'd like to know whether the packets I see (e.g. ARP, DNS, VRRP) are the same in each ethernet configuration (is it dependent on the OS? the driver? the browser even :)?) and which are the conditions in which they appear. Being on the data-link layer, is it maybe even dependent on the physical network (connected to a hub/switch/router)?

Comment: Yes, as you can see if you click the link I provided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answers that talk about using ARP to find the DNS server are generally wrong.

In particular, IP address resolution for off-net IP addresses is *never* done using ARP, and it's not the router's responsibility to answer such an ARP query.

Off-net routing is done by the *client* machine knowing which IP addresses are on the local subnets to which it is connected.  If the requested IP address is not local, then the client machine refers to its routing table to find out which gateway to send the packet to.

Hence in most circumstances the *first* packet sent out will be an ARP request to find the MAC address of the default gateway, if it's not already in the ARP cache.

Only then can it send the DNS query via the gateway.  In this case the packet is sent with the DNS server's IP address in the IP destination field, but with the gateway's MAC address on the ethernet packet.

Answer (score 6):

You can always download [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and take a look.

---

Though to spoil the fun.

Assuming, the IP address of the host is not cached, and the MAC address of the DNS server is not cached, the first thing that will be sent will be a broadcast [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) message trying to find out the MAC address of the DNS server (which the router will respond to with its *own* address).

Next, the host name will be resolved using DNS. Then the returned IP address will be resolved using ARP (again the router will respond with its own address), and finally, the HTTP message will actually be sent.

Comment: So the main influence whether packets appear is caching?

Comment: Yes, even the page could be cached so that no messages would be sent at all.

Comment: this description of ARP for remote servers is completely incorrect.

Comment: You are wrong about the ARP packet to the DNS server. The IP address of the DNS server is usually outside the subnet of the client. If it is, than the client knows that it's no use looking for it on the local network. See Alnitak's answer's to find out what happens instead.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it depends on a variety of initial conditions you left unspecified.

1. Assuming the PC is running an operating system containing a local DNS caching resolver (mine does), the first thing that happens before any packets are sent is the cache is searched for an IP address.  This is complicated, because "www.google.com" isn't a fully-qualified domain name, i.e. it's missing the trailing dot, so the DNS resolver will accept any records already in its cache that match its search domain list first.  For example, if your search domain list is "example.com." followed by "yoyodyne.com." then cached resources matching the names "www.google.com.example.com." "www.google.com.yoyodyne.com." and finally "www.google.com." will be used if available.  Also note: if the web browser is one of the more popular ones, and the PC is running a reasonably current operating system, and the host has at least one network interface with a global scope IPv6 address assigned (and the host is on a network where www.google.com has AAAA records in its DNS horizon), then the remote address of the server might be IPv6 not IPv4.  This will be important later.
2. If the remote address of the Google web server was locally cached in DNS, and the ARP/ND6 cache contains an entry for the IPv4/IPv6 address (respectively) of a default router, then the first transmitted packet will be a TCP SYN packet sourced from the interface address attached to the router and destined for the cached remote IPv4/IPv6 address.  Alternatively, the default router could be reachable over some kind of layer-2 or layer-3 tunnel, in which case, the SYN packet will be appropriately encapsulated.
3. If the remote address of the Google web server was *not* locally cached, then the host will first need to query for the A and/or AAAA records in the DNS domain search list in sequence until it gets a positive response.  If the first DNS resolving server address in the resolver configuration is in one of the local IPv4 subnet ranges, or in a locally attached IPv6 prefix with the L=1 bit set in the router advertisement, and the ARP/ND6 cache already contains an entry for the address in question, then the first packet the host will send is a direct DNS query for either an A record or a AAAA record matching the first fully-qualified domain name in the domain search list.  Alternatively, if the first DNS server is not addressable on-link, and a default router has an ARP/ND6 cache entry already, then the DNS query packet will be sent to the default router to forward to the DNS server.
4. In the event the local on-link DNS server or a default router (respectively, as the case above may be) has no entry in the ARP/ND6 cache, then the first packet the host will send is either an ARP request or an ICMP6 neighbor solicitation for the corresponding address.

Oh, but wait... it's even more horrible.  There are tweaky weird edge cases where the first packet the host sends might be a LLMNR query, an IKE initiation, or... or... or... how much do you really care about all this, buckaroo?

Comment: Exactly this: defining these kinds of preconditions is interesting, as I wouldn't think your answer has changed since then. Going deep inception style :D.

Answer (score 1):

> It depends

Got that right. E.g. does the local DNS cache contain the address? If not then a DNS lookup is likely to be the first thing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, whatever you try to do, the first thing happening is some Ethernet protocol related data. Notably, Ethernet adapters have to decide whether the Ethernet bus is available (so there's some collision detection taking place here)

It's hard to answer your question because it depends a lot on the type of ethernet network you're using. More information on Ethernet transmission can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation)

Answer (score 1):

If the host name is not in DNS cache nor in hosts file, first packet will go to DNS.

Otherwise, the first packet will be HTTP GET.

Comment: Actually, unless the MAC address of the DNS server is cached, the first frame will probably be a broadcast ARP request trying to find out who 201.16.47.53 (the DNS server) is.