# what packet will arrive first when send request

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, dns

As some one mentioned in other forum that interviewer has asked the  question given below.
I dont know exact answer but I would say HTTP request ? Any suggestion and explainations

Imagine a user sitting at an Ethernet-connected PC. He has a browser open. He types   "www.google.com" in the address bar and hits enter.

Now tell me what the first packet to appear on the Ethernet is   .

Thanks

Comment: I'd guess a `ping` (ICMP) packet. I have truthfully no idea, though.

Comment: I guess , firstly it converts name into ip address

Comment: exact duplicate of [First packet to be sent when starting to browse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666864/first-packet-to-be-sent-when-starting-to-browse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no guaranteed always-correct answer, but there are a few likely possibilities.

If the client is configured for [DNS over UDP](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1035/45.htm), then the first packet will be a UDP datagram containing a [DNS query](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1035/39.htm) to resolve `www.google.com` to an IP address.

If the client is configured for [DNS over TCP](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1035/46.htm) and the browser hasn't already got an established TCP connection to the DNS server, the first packet will be part of the connection handshake to DNS, and therefore the answer will be that a `SYN` packet is first out of the gate.

If the browser has been coded to maintain a long-lived TCP connection to the DNS server and assuming the DNS server has allowed the connection to stay alive, the first packet will be a DNS query, sent across the existing connection to that DNS server.

Finally, if the browser had recently visited `www.google.com` recently and is built to do some smart local caching of DNS query results then the first packet will be a SYN to establish a new connection to Google's web server.

If you want to be glib but absolutely precise about it, drop down a layer for your answer and say, *"The first packet out will be an Ethernet frame containing a payload which supports whatever higher-level protocol is needed for the browser to serve up www.google.com".* In fairness, the question is about the Ethernet layer...

Comment: browsers don't maintain long lived TCP connections to DNS servers.  And going down to layer 2 isn't glib, it's the _right answer_. L3 packets can't be exchanged until L2->L3 mappings have been established.

Comment: I'd bet money that the interviewer wasn't asking about the Ethernet layer, though. I'm certain they were testing knowledge of TCP and/or UDP instead.

Comment: How can you possibly second guess that?  FWIW, if I were asking this question of a potential network admin or network app programmer, I _would_ expect them to go down to L2.

Comment: It's an educated guess, that's all, and it's based on the fact that someone asking this and mentioning a browser is likely looking for some knowledge of how a browser is built. Since browser code deals directly only with layer 3 and above, that means the question is likely related to those layers. I agree with you that if this was a network admin interview, the interviewee had better know their L2 facts too.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, with a completely blank slate, the first packet sent will be an ARP broadcast request ("Who has?") from the client PC attempting to discover the MAC address of its default gateway (or of its DNS server if that is on the same subnet as the client).

Comment: @Jack hence "with a completely blank slate"

Answer (score 0):

Interesting :) I just wiresharked it:

```
Client sends a SYN
Server replies with a SYN,ACK
Client sends an ACK
Client sends an HTTP GET
```

(like you mention in your comments the first is obviously the DNS lookup)

Comment: If that is all you saw, the SYN/SYN-ACK/ACK is the TCP connection handshake for the HTTP connection. It's likely that the DNS-IP mapping and the MAC address for the appropriate gateway are being cached.